# Is there relation between eigenvalues of A,B,A+B,AB?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis

I found there are some works about eigenvalues of $A,B,A+B$ in the case of Hermitian matrices. For example, [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/).

I am wondering in the case that $A$ and $B$ is not Hermitian.

For example, my question explicitly regarding the following matrices:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2&-2&0&0&0\\
0&2&-2&0&0\\
0&0&2&-2&0\\
-2&0&0&2&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Note that $A$ is a circulant matrix, and $B$ is not rank-1 matrix.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I would read the question as: "What is the subset of $\mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of tuples $(x,y,z)$ such that there are matrices A,B such that x are the eigenvalues of A, y are the eigenvalues of B and z are the eigenvalues of A+B". Is this correct?

Comment: To state a general theorem about "the eigenvalues of $A$, $B$, $A+B$ and $AB$", there should be a multitude of matrices $A$ and $B$. Do you mean that $A$ is circulant and the lower-left submatrix of $B$ is circulant and the other elements of $B$ are $0$?

Comment: I think this question is related to Horn's problem, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.3633.pdf (and Littlewood-Richardson coefficients)